# Polars how to turn column of type list[list[...]] into ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I know i can turn a normal polars series into a numpy array via `.to_numpy()`.

```
    import polars as pl
    s = pl.Series("a", [1,2,3])
    s
    shape: (3,)
    Series: 'a' [i64]
    [
        1
        2
        3
    ]
    s.to_numpy()
    [1 2 3]
```

However that does not work with a list type. What would be they way to turn such a construct into a 2-D array.

And even more general is there a way to turn a series of list[list[whatever]] into a 3-D and so on?

```
    s = pl.Series("a", [[1,1,1],[1,2,3],[1,0,1]])
    s
    shape: (3,)
    Series: 'a' [list[i64]]
    [
        [1, 1, 1]
        [1, 2, 3]
        [1, 0, 1]
    ]
    s.to_numpy()  # exceptions.ComputeError: 'to_numpy' not supported for dtype: List(Int64)
```

Desired output would be:

```
    [[1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 0, 1]]
```

Or one step further

```
    s = pl.Series("a", [[[1,1],[1,2]],[[1,1],[1,1]]])
    s
    shape: (2,)
    Series: 'a' [list[list[i64]]]
    [
        [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
        [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
    ]
    s.to_numpy()  # exceptions.ComputeError: 'to_numpy' not supported for dtype: List(Int64)

    [[[1 1]
      [1 2]]
    
     [[1 1]
      [1 1]]]
```

Comment: Does polar have a `to_list` method?  In pandas this kind of series would create an object dtype array.  `np.stack` could be used to join the component arrays into one.

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.to_list.html

Comment: That seems to be it. I found out that if i declare numpy as a dependency when installing polars it actually does do `.to_numpy()` on the list[list[int64]] but `np.stack` only manages to remove one level. However np.stack(s.to_list()) works.

Answer (score 2):

You could `explode` the series then reshape the numpy array after. That is probably the only way with the current `ComputeError` specifying it's unsupported in polars. The `list` dtype can have varying list lengths row to row, which would ruin any computation like this, so it makes sense it is not supported.

That said, if you know your list column is of uniform length for every row, this operation can be generally written for any arbitrary nesting of `list` type. It just involves keeping track of the changed dimensions with each `explode`, and then calculating the proper new dimensions:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

def multidimensional_to_numpy(s):
    dimensions = [1, len(s)]
    while s.dtype == pl.List:
        s = s.explode()
        dimensions.append(len(s))
    dimensions = [p[1] // p[0] for p in pairwise(dimensions)]
    return s.to_numpy().reshape(dimensions)
```

```py
multidimensional_to_numpy(pl.Series("a", [1,2,3]))
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64
```

```py
multidimensional_to_numpy(pl.Series("a", [[1,1,1],[1,2,3],[1,0,1]]))

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

```py
multidimensional_to_numpy(pl.Series("a", [[[1,1],[1,2]], [[1,1],[1,1]]]))

array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]], dtype=int64)
```

Note with the soon to be released [Array dtype](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Array.html) that guarantees same-length arrays throughout the column (and the current `arr` will become `list`), this answer could be improved upon in due time (maybe direct to_numpy support there?). In particular, the dimension calculating above should be able to be simplified to tracking the `dtype.width` for each inner array dtype.